# db2 connection error [IBM][CLI Driver] SQL1042C

Tags: db2, db2-connect

```
[2013-05-22 12:29:03,659]**[WARN]**[main]**[SettingsFactory:103]:Could not obtain connection metadata
org.jboss.util.NestedSQLException: Could not create connection; - nested throwable: (COM.ibm.db2.jdbc.DB2Exception: [IBM][CLI Driver] SQL1042C  An unexpected system error occurred.  S
QLSTATE=58004
); - nested throwable: (org.jboss.resource.JBossResourceException: Could not create connection; - nested throwable: (COM.ibm.db2.jdbc.DB2Exception: [IBM][CLI Driver] SQL1042C  An unex
pected system error occurred.  SQLSTATE=58004
))
    at org.jboss.resource.adapter.jdbc.WrapperDataSource.getConnection(WrapperDataSource.java:79)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalDataSourceConnectionProvider.getConnection(LocalDataSourceConnectionProvider.java:81)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory.buildSettings(SettingsFactory.java:72)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSettings(Configuration.java:1881)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1174)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean.newSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:805)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:745)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.AbstractSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractSessionFactoryBean.java:134)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1203)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1172)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:427)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:249)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:155)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:246)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:160)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757)
    at com.yeepay.common.entity.Incrementer.afterPropertiesSet(Incrementer.java:25)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1203)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1172)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:427)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:249)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:155)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:246)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:160)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:352)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:122)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:76)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:85)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:87)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:187)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:800)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:718)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:386)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:249)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:155)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:246)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:160)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.access.SingletonBeanFactoryLocator.useBeanFactory(SingletonBeanFactoryLocator.java:397)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.loadParentContext(ContextLoader.java:317)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:185)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:49)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:3795)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4252)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:760)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:740)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:544)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.commons.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:458)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.RawDynamicInvoker.invoke(RawDynamicInvoker.java:150)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:644)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.init(StandardContext.java:5077)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.commons.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:458)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.RawDynamicInvoker.invoke(RawDynamicInvoker.java:150)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:644)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.tc5.TomcatDeployer.performDeployInternal(TomcatDeployer.java:280)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.tc5.TomcatDeployer.performDeploy(TomcatDeployer.java:88)
    at org.jboss.web.AbstractWebDeployer.start(AbstractWebDeployer.java:357)
    at org.jboss.web.WebModule.startModule(WebModule.java:68)
    at org.jboss.web.WebModule.startService(WebModule.java:46)
    at org.jboss.system.ServiceMBeanSupport.jbossInternalStart(ServiceMBeanSupport.java:274)
    at org.jboss.system.ServiceMBeanSupport.jbossInternalLifecycle(ServiceMBeanSupport.java:230)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor2.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:141)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:80)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:72)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:245)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:644)
    at org.jboss.system.ServiceController$ServiceProxy.invoke(ServiceController.java:943)
    at $Proxy0.start(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.system.ServiceController.start(ServiceController.java:428)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor12.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:141)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:80)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:72)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:245)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:644)
    at org.jboss.mx.util.MBeanProxyExt.invoke(MBeanProxyExt.java:176)
    at $Proxy18.start(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.web.AbstractWebContainer.start(AbstractWebContainer.java:400)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:141)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:80)
    at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.AbstractInterceptor.invoke(AbstractInterceptor.java:118)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:74)
    at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ModelMBeanOperationInterceptor.invoke(ModelMBeanOperationInterceptor.java:127)
    at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.DynamicInterceptor.invoke(DynamicInterceptor.java:80)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:74)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:245)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:644)
    at org.jboss.mx.util.MBeanProxyExt.invoke(MBeanProxyExt.java:176)
    at $Proxy19.start(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.start(MainDeployer.java:989)
    at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.deploy(MainDeployer.java:790)
    at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.deploy(MainDeployer.java:753)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor50.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:141)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:80)
    at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.AbstractInterceptor.invoke(AbstractInterceptor.java:118)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:74)
    at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ModelMBeanOperationInterceptor.invoke(ModelMBeanOperationInterceptor.java:127)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:74)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:245)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:644)
    at org.jboss.mx.util.MBeanProxyExt.invoke(MBeanProxyExt.java:176)
    at $Proxy9.deploy(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.deployment.scanner.URLDeploymentScanner.deploy(URLDeploymentScanner.java:319)
    at org.jboss.deployment.scanner.URLDeploymentScanner.scan(URLDeploymentScanner.java:507)
    at org.jboss.deployment.scanner.AbstractDeploymentScanner$ScannerThread.doScan(AbstractDeploymentScanner.java:192)
    at org.jboss.deployment.scanner.AbstractDeploymentScanner.startService(AbstractDeploymentScanner.java:265)
    at org.jboss.system.ServiceMBeanSupport.jbossInternalStart(ServiceMBeanSupport.java:274)
    at org.jboss.system.ServiceMBeanSupport.jbossInternalLifecycle(ServiceMBeanSupport.java:230)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor2.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:141)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:80)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:72)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:245)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:644)
    at org.jboss.system.ServiceController$ServiceProxy.invoke(ServiceController.java:943)
    at $Proxy0.start(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.system.ServiceController.start(ServiceController.java:428)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor12.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:141)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:80)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:72)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:245)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:644)
    at org.jboss.mx.util.MBeanProxyExt.invoke(MBeanProxyExt.java:176)
    at $Proxy4.start(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.deployment.SARDeployer.start(SARDeployer.java:285)
    at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.start(MainDeployer.java:989)
    at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.deploy(MainDeployer.java:790)
    at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.deploy(MainDeployer.java:753)
    at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.deploy(MainDeployer.java:737)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:141)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:80)
    at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.AbstractInterceptor.invoke(AbstractInterceptor.java:118)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:74)
    at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ModelMBeanOperationInterceptor.invoke(ModelMBeanOperationInterceptor.java:127)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:74)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:245)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:644)
    at org.jboss.mx.util.MBeanProxyExt.invoke(MBeanProxyExt.java:176)
    at $Proxy5.deploy(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.system.server.ServerImpl.doStart(ServerImpl.java:453)
    at org.jboss.system.server.ServerImpl.start(ServerImpl.java:330)
    at org.jboss.Main.boot(Main.java:187)
    at org.jboss.Main$1.run(Main.java:438)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: org.jboss.resource.JBossResourceException: Could not create connection; - nested throwable: (COM.ibm.db2.jdbc.DB2Exception: [IBM][CLI Driver] SQL1042C  An unexpected system
 error occurred.  SQLSTATE=58004
)
    at org.jboss.resource.adapter.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnectionFactory.createManagedConnection(LocalManagedConnectionFactory.java:164)
    at org.jboss.resource.connectionmanager.InternalManagedConnectionPool.createConnectionEventListener(InternalManagedConnectionPool.java:519)
    at org.jboss.resource.connectionmanager.InternalManagedConnectionPool.getConnection(InternalManagedConnectionPool.java:208)
    at org.jboss.resource.connectionmanager.JBossManagedConnectionPool$BasePool.getConnection(JBossManagedConnectionPool.java:529)
    at org.jboss.resource.connectionmanager.BaseConnectionManager2.getManagedConnection(BaseConnectionManager2.java:410)
    at org.jboss.resource.connectionmanager.TxConnectionManager.getManagedConnection(TxConnectionManager.java:342)
    at org.jboss.resource.connectionmanager.BaseConnectionManager2.allocateConnection(BaseConnectionManager2.java:462)
    at org.jboss.resource.connectionmanager.BaseConnectionManager2$ConnectionManagerProxy.allocateConnection(BaseConnectionManager2.java:894)
    at org.jboss.resource.adapter.jdbc.WrapperDataSource.getConnection(WrapperDataSource.java:73)
    ... 177 more
Caused by: COM.ibm.db2.jdbc.DB2Exception: [IBM][CLI Driver] SQL1042C  An unexpected system error occurred.  SQLSTATE=58004

    at COM.ibm.db2.jdbc.app.SQLExceptionGenerator.throw_SQLException(Unknown Source)
    at COM.ibm.db2.jdbc.app.SQLExceptionGenerator.check_return_code(Unknown Source)
    at COM.ibm.db2.jdbc.app.DB2Connection.connect(Unknown Source)
    at COM.ibm.db2.jdbc.app.DB2Connection.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at COM.ibm.db2.jdbc.app.DB2Driver.connect(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.resource.adapter.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnectionFactory.createManagedConnection(LocalManagedConnectionFactory.java:154)
    ... 185 more
```

Answer (score 0):

You should probably check the db2diag.log file
Errors of this SQLSTATE are starting to get common. I believe you check your diag log and if needed raise a PMR for the same to the IBM people.